# Reducing run time with pandas accessors

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I have the following call:

```
def compute_using_AA(self):

    k=0

    while k<self.nobs:
        L = 0
        self.BB.ix[k]=0.0
        while L<self.nobs:
            self.BB.ix[k] = self.BB.ix[k]+self.AA[k,L]*self.detrend.ix[L]
            L+=1
        k+=1
```

And in profiling I see:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
8    1.510    0.189   59.611    7.451   Data.py:47(compute_using_AA)
```

Where:

```
type(AA)=<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(BB) =<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

and

`type(detrend)=<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Are there any low hanging fruit recommendations that may help me to speed things up?

Comment: Can you clarify as to what is the original data and expected output?

Comment: I have added an answer with my thoughts, but as @Leb put it, complete your post with some data, maybe a minimal running example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious thing I see is that you should use numpy array operations. The computation going on inside the inner loop does not depend on the values of BB, it is just an accumulator. So you can perform point-by-point multiplication on `AA` an `detrend`, sum everything, and store in BB. It actually looks like you're just performing a linear product of two vectors, where the second is always the same, and the first is stored in a matrix. This could be performed with:

```
def compute_using_AA(self):
    self.BB.ix = np.dot(self.AA, self.detrend.ix)
```

This will result in an array with the same size as BB.ix with its elements being the sum of the products of each row in AA by detrend.